# how to write a Lua pattern to convert string (nested array) into a real array?

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

I would like to convert a string into an array (a small map in a game with coordinates, colors, etc.), the string represents a nested array, and I am not sure how to do it. I would like to open an array after the first { , then open an array after each { , and read the key/value until the }  :

```
function stringToArray()
    local Array = {}
    local txt = "{ {Group = 123, Pos = 200}, {Group = 124, Pos = 205} }"
    for str in string.gmatch(txt, .....
end
```

Comment: Lua has no regex support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since the string is actually valid lua syntax you can simply execute it using `load()`

for example

```
local txt = "{ {Group = 123, Pos = 200}, {Group = 124, Pos = 205} }"
local Array = load("return " .. txt)()
print(Array[1].Group) --prints 123
```

Note: for lua version 5.1 or lower it is the function `loadstring()`

Comment: Thanks, but I have got an error : Bad argument #1 to 'load' (function expected, got string) on the line : local Array = ...

Comment: @Leo_xfh can you try `loadstring` instead? depending on which lua version it is called like that

Comment: This lacks sandboxing and is thus insecure for user-provided data.

Answer (score 1):

Without such functions that are possibly sandboxed like load() for example
you have to parse the string and construct (key/value pairs) what you want.
A good idea for further decisions/conditions and analyzing could be
to count what is not needed to construct...

```
local txt = "{ {Group = 123, Pos = 200}, {Group = 124, Pos = 205} }"
local _, lcurlies = txt:gsub('%{','')
local _, rcurlies = txt:gsub('%}','')
local _, commas = txt:gsub(',','')
local _, spaces = txt:gsub('%s','')
local _, equals = txt:gsub('=','')

print(lcurlies,rcurlies,commas,spaces,equals)
-- Puts out: 3  3   3   13  4
```